# Trustees Being Ignored on NSS Volume

Tags: linux, sles, nss, novell

I'm trying to figure out what's going on here. I migrated a server from NW6.5SP8 to OES2 Linux. All the trustees on the NSS volumes came over and at some point in the past week, they started being ignored. It's almost as if all the users have supervisor rights from the top down. I don't see this set anywhere. What's going on?

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Holy cow... someone had given the Organization supervisor rights to the TREE :O

Comment: *headdesk* Yowza. Glad you caught that!

Comment: That happens.  Ah well.  The silliness that can ensue with trustees!

Comment: Yeah... I wish we had nSure audit running, I want to know who put it there!